# Using alias targets in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

When defining CMake targets one can create alias targets so that the alias name can be used to refer to the defined target in subsequent commands. For instance

```
add_library(foo_lib foo.cpp bar.cpp bat.cpp)
add_library(foo::lib ALIAS foo_lib)
```

As far as I understood it, this has the advantage that the name `foo_lib` doens't appear as a make target. However, given such an alias name I'd like to set all kinds of properties to them such as:

```
set_target_properties(foo::lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ...)
target_include_directories(foo::lib PUBLIC ... PRIVATE ...)
```

but this is not possible unfortunately, since *CMake Error: set_target_properties can not be used on an ALIAS target*. I don't see why this shouldn't be possible as I'd like to define the name of my lib once and refer to the given alias whenever I want to adjust a property of the target. Any hints on how to use ALIAS targets "correctly"? What is the purpose of ALIAS targets other than they're not appearing as Make targets then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*ALIAS* similar to "synonym". *ALIAS* target is just another name for original one. So the requirement for *ALIAS* target to be *non-modifiable* - you cannot adjust its properties, install it, etc.

One of possible scenarios for creating alias: Having a target, which **conceptionally differs** from the original one, but which is **effectively the same** (e.g., in the specific configuration):

```
if(FOO_USE_SHIPPED)
    add_library(FOO ...) # Library FOO shipped with our project
endif()

...

# We need FOO_test for testing
if(FOO_USE_SHIPPED)
    add_library(FOO_test ALIAS FOO) # Use our library
else()
    add_library(FOO_test IMPORTED)
    set_target_property(FOO_test ...) # Use external library
endif()
```

Comment: ALIAS also help with the fact that cmake expands not existing variables to empty strings and therefore add better type handling. In the context of modern cmake alias also provide a consistent way to add dependencies and it does not matter where this dependency comes from. Check Pfeifer's talk on modern cmake.

Answer (score 1):

`ALIAS` targets are extremely important in CMake because `target_link_libraries` searches for targets that are passed to them.  Since [CMP0028](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0028.html), if the target name passed to `target_link_libraries` is either an `ALIAS` or an `IMPORTED` target then CMake doesn't fall back to assuming it might be a library file name.

This means that CMake is able to validate during CMake's config stage whether an `ALIAS` target was actually defined by CMake, and doesn't just fall back to assuming the undefined target should be a library file somewhere that's to be resolved at the end of the build stage.  Consequently, if you screwed up setting up an `ALIAS` target, CMake catches the error much earlier in the process.