# What is the point of ALIAS in cmake?

Tags: cmake

In a lot of tutorials and cmake examples I see, it is suggested that you provide aliases with `::`s in the name:

```
add_library(foo a.cxx b.cxx c.xx)
add_library(N::foo ALIAS foo)
```

What is the point of doing such a thing? Is there a case where using `N::foo` subsequently solves a problem that using `foo` directly might have? Why is this considered good practice?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Why have ALIAS for IMPORTED libraries?

Comment: Hm, yes, my previous comment was wrong. Moreover, [ALIAS is forbidden for IMPORTED targets](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2015-May/060576.html). Actually, IMPORTED was actually my reflex on namespace (`N::`).

Answer (score -1):

Citing the documentation regarding [alias targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets):

> A primary use-case for `ALIAS` targets is for example or unit test
>   executables accompanying a library, which may be part of the same
>   buildsystem or built separately based on user configuration.
>
> ```
> add_library(lib1 lib1.cpp)
> install(TARGETS lib1 EXPORT lib1Export ${dest_args})
> install(EXPORT lib1Export NAMESPACE Upstream:: ${other_args})
>
> add_library(Upstream::lib1 ALIAS lib1)
> ```

With other words, as alias with different computer systems, it makes the names less technical and more human-readable / user-friendly.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I have no idea what it means?

Comment: @Barry: The library defined by this example can be referenced outside with the **same name** whenever other project includes given one (via `add_subdirectory`) or uses `find_package()` for locate its installation. Without *ALIAS* such "dualness" is possible only without *NAMESPACE* option for exporting, either providing target `lib1` which is "less unique", or forcing the author of the project to use fully-qualified name `add_library(Upstream::lib1 ...)`. However, I find using ALIAS in *other project*, like in [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021910/3440745) is more native.